# Have to manually 'startx' after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: xorg, 18.04

I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 today. I didn't see any errors during the upgrade, but now when I boot I only get a graphical console. However, `startx` brings up the Gnome desktop just fine, so I don't think that there are any fundamental problems.

Grep'ing shows that there are no `EE` entries in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Where should I be looking to restore the normal graphical boot?

Comment: Exactly the same problem, except I didn't upgrade. Got a fresh Ubuntu Server installation onto which I installed `ubuntu-desktop -no-install-recommends`. I think we can register an `initctl` job to run `startx`, but that doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends`, it fixed the problem for me. Think I accidentally deleted something important when cleaning up the stock Ubuntu junk applications. The command installed extra 3500 kB of _something_, and now GUI starts as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Re-initialising gdm3 has helped:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Although it took two reboots for my system to be completely happy again.

Comment: Before need to check  sudo systemctl enable gdm3 and sudo systemctl start gdm3